# how do i fix this in android gradle build?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, interface

after executing  build it returns build failed with the following error:
(Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): android.view.MenuItem)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a feature that is only supported in newer android versions,  just change your minimum api version to 24. See [this](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/change-api-sdk-level-android-studio.html) link for advice on how to do that.